# SBS 2003 to SBS 2008 but keep old server online

Tags: windows-server-2008, migration, windows-sbs

I have a client running SBS 2003 and they are ready to upgrade to SBS 2008.  They have a couple of programs that will not run on SBS 2008 and thus cannot be migrated.  Is there a way to keep the old SBS 2003 server online as a "member" server or does it have to be turned off.  I know with SBS 2008 they added a new feature where you can purchase an "add on" license and run a 2008 Server Std edition along side of the SBS 2008 box, will this work in my scenario?

Thanks in advance.
msindle

Comment: This can be done with a registry hack and disabling a service, but Im on my phone right now and can't find the similar question that's on this site about it.

Comment: Sweet that would work for me, let me know if you can find it.  Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the duplicate on Server Fault (maybe it wasn't on here after all), but I used the following instructions when I went on holiday halfway through a migration:

http://byronwright.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/stop-sbs-from-shutting-down.html

> - Tools you'll need – Process Explorer from http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/ProcessesAndThreads/ProcessExplorer.mspx
>
> As you probably know, you have a service called SBCore or "SBS Core
>   Services", which executes the following process:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sbscrexe.exe. If you kill it, it just restarts –
>   and if you try and stop it you are told Access Denied.
>
> If you fire up Process Explorer, you can select the process and
>   Suspend it, now we can start to disable the thing. Run regedit and
>   expand the nodes until you reach the following hive
>   /key:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SBCore Right
>   click this, hit permissions and give the "Administrators" group on the
>   local machine full access ( don't forget to replace permissions on
>   child nodes ). F5 in regedit and you'll see all of the values and data
>   under this key.
>
> Select the "Start" DWORD and change it from 2 to 4 – this basically
>   sets the service to the "Disabled" state as far as the MMC services
>   snap-in (and windows for that matter) is concerned.
>
> Next, adjust the permissions on the file
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sbscrexe.exe so that EVERYONE account is denied
>   any sort of access to this file. Then go back to process explorer, and
>   kill the sbscrexe.exe process, if it doesn't restart –
>   congratulations!
>
> Load up the services MMC snap-in and you should find that "SBS Core
>   Services" is stopped and marked as Disabled.

Comment: Fantastic, that looks like it'll work!  Thanks again Mark!